# web.config 301 redirects, windows hosting

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I'm struggling to get the web.config file working for redirects - I'm doing this for the first time. I've been trying plenty of different codes which I found on this site and elsewhere. 
We have HTTPS site and I need to redirect HTTP url-s to HTTPS.  The website is written in HTML and we have Windows hosting.

I set up a web.config file and added the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something here?
Or does it need some time to take effect?

Many thanks in advance!

Kadri

Comment: Okay, so what is happening? What is / are there any errors?

Comment: Nothing happens. The http doesn't get redirected to https. No error messages.

Answer (score 0):

From Scott Hanselman's [blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) a few years ago, you should try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives "500 - Internal server error" message.

Comment: It looks like I made a mistake in the `<match url="(.*)" />` element before.  I've updated the sample and both it and your original example work on my machine here (Windows 10).  Do you have the [url rewrite extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed?

Comment: The company where our website is hosted said that: 
1:Microsoft rewrite modules are installed. 
2: The certificate is installed on a separate secure server to which your domain is pointing for content.
 3: REQUIRE SSL is not the default. This is triggered by adding the redirect to https:// 
4: The web config file is already created, and you will need a suitable redirect to https:// on it.

 I feel like they are not very helpful. What do they mean by saying suitable redirect to https://?

Comment: I think I need some more context.  Are you using a hosting company or hosting yourself? Do you have access to modify the `web.config`?  Do you have ASP.NET /  MVC in your site, or are you just serving static content?

Comment: We are using a hosting company. They asked me to create a web.config file, so I used the code you provided and dropped the file into the server. It isn't ASP.NET, just a simple static website written in html/css and some javascript. If it helps the website is www.josephalan.co.uk.